# javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: Cannot resolve element with ID 1234. Solution provided at the end

Tags: java, xml, cxf, xml-signature

I'm having the following workflow process:

1. Get XML as a String
2. Convert String to Document, Sign(some elements) the document and return it back in String
3. Get Signed XML as a String, convert it to a Document and Validate the Signature

Here is the Signature creation method:

```
public static String createXMLDSign(String xmlString) throws Exception{
    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to
    // generate the enveloped signature.
    String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

    // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/jks/client-keystore.jks"), keyStorePass .toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
        (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry
            ("client-keypair", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPass .toCharArray()));
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
    KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
    List x509Content = new ArrayList();
    x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    x509Content.add(cert);
    X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
    KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    // Instantiate the document to be signed.
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse
            (new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));


    // Get element which will be signed
    Element child =(Element)doc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:Eid").item(0);
    child.setAttribute("Id", "1234");
    child.setIdAttribute("Id", true); 
    String id = child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("Id").getNodeValue();
    String uri = String.format("#%s", id);

    List<Transform> transformList = new LinkedList<>();
    transformList.add(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null));
    Reference reference = fac.newReference(uri,
            fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null), transformList, null, null);

    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(
            CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), fac
            .newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null), Collections.singletonList(reference));

    // Remove element from the Node
    Node node = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:Eis").item(0);
    Node eumNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:EumSignature").item(0);
    node.removeChild(eumNode);

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
    // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element.
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext
        (keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), /*doc.getDocumentElement()*/node);
    dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");

    // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);

    // Marshal, generate, and sign the enveloped signature.
    signature.sign(dsc);

    /////////////Signature verification
    // Find Signature element.
    signVerification(fac, doc, signature);

    // Convert DocToString and verify
    String stringDoc = Utils.docToString(doc);
    // Instantiate the document to be signed.
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf2.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc2 = dbf2.newDocumentBuilder().parse
            (new InputSource(new StringReader(stringDoc)));
    signVerification(fac, doc2, signature);

    /////////////////////////
    return Utils.docToString(doc);

}
```

NOTE: I add manually “Id” attribute in the element which I want to Sign because it doesn't exist in original XML.

Here is the method used for docToString conversion:

```
public static String docToString(Document doc) {
    try {
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Execution result** First Validation passed successfully but the second after the conversions failed with an error:

> javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 1234
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:431)
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.validate(DOMReference.java:393)
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.validate(DOMXMLSignature.java:278)
>       at com.innonetworks.utils.XmlSignatureHelper.signVerification(XmlSignatureHelper.java:185)
>       at com.innonetworks.utils.XmlSignatureHelper.createXMLDSign(XmlSignatureHelper.java:160)
>       at com.innonetworks.interceptor.XMLDSignInterceptor.changeOutboundMessage(XMLDSignInterceptor.java:36)
>       at com.innonetworks.interceptor.MessageChangeInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageChangeInterceptor.java:56)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>       at com.innonetworks.interceptor.MessageChangeInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageChangeInterceptor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:440)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:355)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
>       at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.es1RegisterEIS(Unknown Source)
>       at com.innonetworks.es1.client.SoapClientApp.callSoapClient(SoapClientApp.java:178)
>       at com.innonetworks.es1.client.SoapClientApp.main(SoapClientApp.java:63)
>   Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID 1234
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMURIDereferencer.dereference(DOMURIDereferencer.java:134)
>       at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference.dereference(DOMReference.java:425)
>       ... 18 more

**NOTE** If I replace the Reference parameter "uri" with "" the both Verification passed successfully

**SOLUTION**
I fixed the problem and would like to share if can help somebody else. The solution I found in Oracle page [JDK-8017265 : XMLSignature Cannot Resolve ID](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8017265)

I used the second workaround - Register the ID elements with the DOMValidateContext.setIdAttributeNS method before validating the signature

Here is the code:

```
DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext
        (new X509KeySelector(), nl.item(0));
     final NodeList elements = docNew.getElementsByTagName("ns2:EumSignedInfo");
    if (elements.getLength() > 0) {
        valContext.setIdAttributeNS((Element) elements.item(0), null, "Id");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with this error

Comment: The Oracle bug tracker link is broken. Here's the corrected link: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8017265